# Paypal error #10602 on magento

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I am getting below error when making an invoice on a product

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Authorization has already been
>   completed (#10602: Authorization completed).

I've read what's the error about ([here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/)) but I don't know how to fix it.

The product's status is still "processing" and I want that to be changed to "complete".

Short back-story: we migrated the magento site on a testing server first with a different domain name.

Answer (score 0):

From that error, it sounds like you are trying to authorize a payment that's already been authorized. Are you trying to do authorizations? Try changing the transaction processing mode to sale.